# Next13 (App Directory) + Google Tag Manager + Google Analytics (Tags Not Firing)

Tags: next.js, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, next.js13

Struggling with integrating Google Tag Manager + Google Analytics Tag with Next 13 (App Directory). Not sure whether the problem is more with Next13 or with my Tag Manager setup (though there is not so much to set up, actually)

I have been following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/valse/how-to-setup-google-tag-manager-in-a-next-13-app-router-website-248p). With this, am I supposed to activiate History Change Triggers in Google Tag Manager?

When I do send events via

```
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'pageview',
    page: url,
  })
```

I do see a `pageview` event in my Google Tag Manager Preview, but my Google Analytics Tag isn't fired, even though I have it set to trigger on "All Pages". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I create components and use them in the main layout :

```
"use client";
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
import React from "react";

const GoogleTag = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="google-site-verification"
          content="1jRUAxx6jZc-abqxxoa-rtI-6prcxxznoxxEKC6xxESTjxxq89FcIbg"
        />
      </Head>
      <Script
        async
        src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxx"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
      />
      <Script
        id="google"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: ` window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
    
            gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxx');`,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoogleTag;
```